# LinqToSql Equivalent to IN

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How can do in LinqToSql an equivalent to the IN clause?

I have a SQL statement like this:

```sql
select *
from funktion 
where institution_id IN (select id from institution where kreis_id = 36)
```

How can I express that in a Linq-to-Sql statement?

For explanation: the table `funktion` is something like `CAPACITY` and the table `institution` is representing INSTITUTIONS with hierarchy structure.

Every function is referenced between the tables with `institution.id == funktion.institution_id`. The hierarchy structures are from high to low: VERBAND, BEZIRK, KREIS, VEREIN.

Every VERBAND consists of several BEZIRK. Each BEZIRK consist of several KREIS. Each KREIS consist of several VEREIN. Every Hierarchy-layer has its ID for lower layers in referenced ID columns. So the lowest layer has a beside its own ID (Primary Key) a column for KREIS_ID, BEZIRK_ID, VERBAND_ID to know to which next levels it belongs. So I have to make statements for each layer to see the functions of all lower levels.

In my SQL example shown earlier, I have a `KREIS` that needs to get all `FUNCTIONS` where the `INSTITUTION_ID` is in a select of IDS where the `KREIS_ID` is like the `OWN_ID` (here for example 36).

I hope someone could help me. I am very new in LINQ, ,but have to change old software structures to a newer DataSource.

Comment: Can you provide ef model classes ?

Comment: No. I have solved it meanwhile with a join and where-condition. open for better solutions

Comment: If the `funktion` and `institution` tables have a FK relationship you shlould have Navigation properties where you can do something like `from x in db.funktion where x.institution.kreis_id == 36`

Comment: In LinqToSQL, provided you have set your relationships in the database and built your dvml around it, you don't n ed anything special to do this and it would simply be something like: db.Funktions.Where(f => f.Instititution.Kreis_id == 36).

Answer (score 3):

The IN statement in linq is Contains(). You can do something like:

```cs
var institutions = db.Institutions.Where(i => i.kreisId == 36).Select(i => i.id);
var funktions = db.Funktion.Where(f => institutions.Contains(f.instition_id)).ToList();
```

Comment: but how do this with a (select IDs from somewhere) instead of the 36?

Comment: This should be `f => db.Instituitions.Where(i => i.kreis_id == 36).Select(i => i.id).Contains(f.institution_id))`

Comment: Note there is no overload of `Contains` that take a delegate.  You pass it the value you want to find in the collection.

Comment: `f => myList.Contains(f.Id == 36)` only works if `myList` is a list of `bool`

Comment: You should just delete that first bit of code as it's completely wrong and just leave your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with a JOIN in combination with WHERE:

```
from funktion in db.funktion
where funktion.deletedFlag == 0 && (funktion.bis == null || funktion.bis > DateTime.Now)
                            
join institution in db.institution on funktion.institution_id equals institution.id
where institution.kreis_id == mySession.Current.benutzer.institution_id
                     
select new
{
  ...
});
```

Comment: Using a join in the actual SQL would generally be considered better practice than using IN anyway.  The join would be more efficient, although most modern DBs would likely turn your query into a join in the execution plan anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
   class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //select * from funktion where institution_id IN (select id from institution where kreis_id = 36)
            Context db = new Context();
            var results = db.funktion.Select(x => db.institution.Where(y => (x.institution_id == y.id) && (y.kreis_id == 36))).ToList();
 
        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<funktion> funktion { get; set; }
        public List<institution> institution { get; set; }
    }
    public class funktion
    {
        public string institution_id { get; set; }
    }
    public class institution
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int kreis_id { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This results in a `List<IQueryable<bool>>` which I don't think is correct.  I assume you meant to use a `Where` and `Any` instead of two `Select`s

Comment: The 2nd select should of been a where.

Comment: Now it's a `List<IQuerable<institution>>` which is still wrong.

Comment: The OP is looking for a `List<funktion>`.  Like I said before if you did `Where` and then an `Any` inside this would be correct